# executing php script in console

Tags: php, scripting, console

i'm trying to execute a php in the console, but each time i run it:

```
php myscript.php
```

it only outputs the content of the file, it dowsn't run it.
output:

```
<?
echo 'test';
?>
```

instead of:

```
test
```

What's wrong? I have php installed under c:/program files/php and the environment variable is set.

Thanks,

Dave

Comment: Make sure the /folder.to/php.exe in your path so php.exe can be called
from any folder on your system

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try

```
<?php
```

It might be [`short_open_tag`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.short-open-tag) is disabled in your php.ini

> Tells PHP whether the short form (`<? ?>`) of PHP's open tag should be allowed. If you want to use PHP in combination with XML, you can disable this option in order to use `<?xml ?>`  inline. Otherwise, you can print it with PHP, for example: `<?php echo '<?xml version="1.0"?>'; ?>`. Also, if disabled, you must use the long form of the PHP open tag (`<?php ?>`).

---

Edit: You might also want to read [Are Short Open Tags Acceptable To Use?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/200640/are-php-short-tags-acceptable-to-use)

Comment: thanks everyone, since gordon posted first, he will get the accepted answer

Answer (score 4):

Try:

```
<?php
```

instead of

```
<?
```

(if that works you may need to configure your installation of PHP to enable short tags.)

Answer (score 1):

Don't use short tags. Replace  `<?` with `<?php`.

Comment: it can't work, unless s/he adds the `#!` line with the proper interpreters for the file, and set the eXecutable "bit"

Answer (score 1):

use `<?php` instead of `<?`

**edit** Try also the `-n` flags from the cmd line, it avoids PHP read the ini file where short tag could be disabled